# Embedding plot of Minkowski

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics

I am trying to obtain the embedding diagram of Minkowski space. I took the metric:

$$ d s^{2} = - d t^{2} + d r^{2} + r^{2} \left( d \theta^{2} + \sin^{2} \theta d \phi^{2}\right) $$

for $t =$ cte and $\theta = \pi /2$,

$$ d s^{2} = d r^{2} + r^{2} d \phi^{2} $$

I know this should give me a disk, like the one below:

[image]

But I can't understand how to graph or if I should do any parameterization before. I know it's something basic but I would really appreciate if someone could guide me.

Comment: You need to define suitable co-ordinates for it. In the case of Minkowski, I think it will be the hyperbolic ones.

Comment: @codebpr In hyperbolic coordinates, the Minkowski line element is expressed as
$$  d s^{2} = d \rho^{2} + \sinh^{2} \rho d \theta ^{2} $$
but I can't figure out how to graph it as a 3D surface with Mathematica

Comment: What assumptions did you use to transform in hyperbolic coordinates?

Comment: @codebpr I considered minkowski at 2+1,
$$ d s^{2} = -\mathrm{d} X_0^2+\mathrm{d} X_1^2+\mathrm{d} X_2^2 $$

and the transformation:

$$ \begin{aligned}
& X_0=\cosh \rho \\
& X_1=\sinh \rho \cos \theta \\
& X_2=\sinh \rho \sin \theta
\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us follow your assumptions and say you had Minkowski spacetime in rectangular coordinates:

$$ds^2=-dX_0^2+dX_1^2+dX_2^2$$

Now, using your transformation:

$$X_0=\cosh\rho,$$
$$X_1=\sinh\rho\cos\theta,$$
$$X_2=\sinh\rho\sin\theta.$$

Then, after solving, we get the following, for a unit hyperbolic radius:

$$ds^2=d\rho^2+\sinh^2\rho d\theta^2$$

You have everything; all you need is just to plug your transformation rules in Mathematica:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sinh[ρ]  Cos[θ], Sinh[ρ]  Sin[θ], Cosh[ρ]}, {ρ, 0, 0.01}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

which gives you the required embedding diagram,

[image: embedding]

Comment: amazing, thank you very much!